# Updating iOS app text view and image view in real time

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous

I've just started out in iOS app development and have become confused about how text and photos should be handled. I have an app with several screens that consist of just one photo and a couple of paragraphs of text. I want to be able to update these fields regularly without having to resubmit the app to the App Store. Some of the screens are a copy of a blog posted online. So my question is how best to set up the xCode project.  Should I be using a database like Firebase to bring the information in or should I be using the WebView? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the needs of your application. For a simple application like this, both methods can be a right decision. I would recommend using native UILabels and UIImageViews, mainly for performance issues.

Comment: and where would you recommend that I store the data?

Comment: Maybe you can store it locally in UserDefaults or inside a CoreData database.